# Method to detect Protein aggregation

Tags: methods, prion, fret

I have a specific human protein that was purified from E. coli.

- This protein was tagged with MBP and diluted in an elution buffer.
- This protein has a tendency to aggregate, and when it does, it can induce the nearest protein to be aggregated too.
- We believe that tagging MBP prevents this protein from aggregating, so that when MBP is cut off from the protein, it will easily aggregate.
- I want to confirm this. However, I am not sure how to check if the protein is aggregating or not.

I would like to know whether my protein is aggregated, what is the best method to detect protein aggregation?. I would really appreciate if anyone can give me the reference or protocol.

Comment: What do you mean by "my protein is aggregated"? In a sample preparation? In cells?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. We are happy to try to assist people with biological problems, but we can only do that if we know what the problem is. So, first, please finish reading the [Tour] (we know you haven’t) and then read the Help on asking good questions. You are so close to your own problem that you think more experienced scientists must know what it’s all about. We haven’t a clue! What is your protein? Is it pure, in a mixture, in a cell or what? Why do you think it might be aggregated? Tell us what you are doing and what you observe. Only then can we help you

Comment: Thank you so much.  Let me provide some background: I have a specific type of human protein that was purified from E. coli. This protein was tagged with MBP and diluted in an elution buffer. This protein has a tendency to aggregate, and when it does, it can induce the nearest protein to be aggregated too. We believe that tagging MBP prevents this protein from aggregating, so that when MBP is cut off from the protein, it will easily aggregate. I want to confirm this. However, I am not sure how to check if the protein is aggregating or not.  If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: @Sketsawy you need to tag people with the "@" to let them know that you are talking to them. Also, the information that you've provided in your comment would be very helpful included directly in the question, so I'm going to edit your question to include it there.

Answer (score 2):

I started writing a comment but it got out of hand so I'm just doing an answer.

There are many many papers that describe methods for detecting aggregation. Below is a semi-random sample.

What exactly is the roadblock that you are encountering? Which of these kinds of methods have you tried? Are you working in live cells or only in vitro? Are you open to putting your protein into yeast?

- [Removing MBP tags from proteins](http://www.protocol-online.org/biology-forums-2/posts/22454.html)
- [Methods in pharma for detecting aggregation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3063870/) (older).
- [Methods in biomanufacturing for detecting/managing aggregation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378517318306215).
- Papers with informative methods sections for testing aggregation (mostly in yeast, which is probably the easiest system for studying prions):
- - https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6980781/
- - https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6980676/
- - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0076687906120121
- - https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5066306/
- - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1046202306000594
- [Visualizing aggregates in live cells](https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/cbic.202100443)
- [Microscopy of aggregates in live cells](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29221925/)